# Promise dentro de promise não aguarda Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, promises

Eae galera estou com um problema, eu recebo varios objetos onde eu mapeio eles, faço uma consulta externa usando o axios e salvo seu retorno. Vamos ao codigo:

```
let savedClients = Object.entries(documents).map(personDocument => {
    let [person, document] = personDocument
    documentFormated = document
    documentNumbers = document.replace(/\D/g, '')

    return ConsultDocuments.getResponse(documentNumbers).then(resultScore => { // Chamando o axios
        const info = { ...resultScore }
        return Save.saveClient(info)
    })
})

Promise.all(savedClients).then(results => {
    console.log(results) // Vem só o ultimo objeto salvo varias vezes
})
```

O poblema é que ele realiza o map inteiro primeiro, depois faz as consultas com o ultimo resultado varias vezes (o total de documentos passados)

Este codigo é um legado e usar async/await não funciona (serio, se nao eu nem estaria aqui)

Eu já tentei N formas, e com a biblioteca Q, ele faz na ordem certa mas nao espera o axios, os resultados vem todos com pending

Valeu.

Comment: Consegue informar qual é o conteúdo da variável `documents`?

Comment: { nome: cpf } exemplo, { fulano : 12312312398 }